# PowerBI: Creation of a matrix visual with aggregation on 2 different columns with similar set of values

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

so I have a huge table (50 mm) of purchase transactions data. For each transaction seller and buyer is recorded. Sellers and buyers come from the same list of customers (think of eBay like situation where each user can serve as both seller or a buyer).

Sample data

| Seller | Buyer | Amount | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |
| Customer A | Customer C | 30 $ | 1 |
| Customer C | Customer B | 10 $ | 1 |
| Customer B | Customer A | 120 $ | 1 |
| Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |

And I would like to create a matrix visual as follows:

| User | Sold $ | Purchased $ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | 130 $ | 120 $ |
| Customer B | 120 $ | 110 $ |
| Customer C | 10 $ | 30 $ |

How I did - I added separate seller and Buyer view and a field User into my data and used the view column to sumif into my sold and purchased measures (see example below). However, while this solution is solving my task it is also doubling the size of my dataset. I wonder if anybody can offer a more elegant solution.

User Column is equal to Seller for sales view and is equal to buyer for Purchase view.

Thank you!

New dataset

| View | User | Seller | Buyer | Amount | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | Customer A | Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |
| Sales | Customer A | Customer A | Customer C | 30 $ | 1 |
| Sales | Customer C | Customer C | Customer B | 10 $ | 1 |
| Sales | Customer B | Customer B | Customer A | 120 $ | 1 |
| Sales | Customer A | Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |
| Purchase | Customer B | Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |
| Purchase | Customer C | Customer A | Customer C | 30 $ | 1 |
| Purchase | Customer B | Customer C | Customer B | 10 $ | 1 |
| Purchase | Customer A | Customer B | Customer A | 120 $ | 1 |
| Purchase | Customer B | Customer A | Customer B | 50 $ | 1 |